# Creating password cache with python in linux

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, passwords

I am a network engineer and my goal is to make python script where I can only be asked by the network devices for a password one time. Then after that, the password I entered will be securely cache (in ubuntu) and devices will not asked me again every time i'll login to the devices.

I don't want to store the password in a file because it is not secure. That cache should expire after 24 hours or the devices is rebooted.

We are using ubuntu to remotely login to our devices.

I have tried to look for solutions but I couldn't find one.

Comment: You could use a database like `mongodb` and use a [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) to make documents expire after 24 hours, and on insert use `base64` to encode the password.

Comment: Any method of storage that lasts between login sessions will almost certainly have to involve a file.

Comment: @Jab `base64` isn't encryption, it's no more secure than storing plaintext.

Comment: Are you sure you can't use SSH key files instead of having to enter a password? And use a keychain manager?

Comment: @Barmar Yes you're right, my bad. [simple-crypt](https://github.com/andrewcooke/simple-crypt) is a decent way though.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I think i'll just use keyring.